# Can we use images in one image density without any quality lost? (Android Image Density)

Tags: android, image, kotlin, animation

I work on an image sequence animation. I have 75 png files. I want to use images in one size without adding mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi etc types and get the same view on all devices. Is there a way to do this?

Best,

Answer (score 0):

You Can try the following way may help you

(1)use only mipmap-xhdpi folder and create image according to mipmap-xhdpi density requireda and put all in xhdpi.

(2)Use Vector Drawable/Vector Graphic features in Android studio....Please read detail from https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

(3)Please try to create the nine-patch image...Please read from https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawables#nine-patch.
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch